# Show softkeyboard on top of showDialog in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am displaying list in showDialog with textformfield on top to search from list. When ever user clicks on Textformfield keyboard is displayed but it pushes the dialog up.
This doen't looks good from users experience. Is there a way to keep the showDialog at same position when keyboard is displayed. If the showDialog box is too long keyboard should overlap the dialog box.

i have searched a lot but havn't found any solution to this

Answer (score 0):

By the framework, the `showDialog` will change the size when the keyboard opens from the bottom. But, we can avoid the show dialog's bottom clipping issue by setting the `AlertDialog.scrollable property` to `true`. Find the sample code below.

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      scrollable: true,
                      content: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 100,
                                child: Text('Employee Name'),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                  height: 45.0, width: 100, child: TextField()),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 100,
                                child: Text('Employee Id'),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                  height: 45.0, width: 100, child: TextField()),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 100,
                                child: Text('City'),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                  height: 45.0, width: 100, child: TextField()),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              child: Text('Click Me')),
        ));
```